# How do left-handed people hold smartphones?

Tags: usability, mobile, ergonomics

Is it with their left hand, using its thumb to tap UI elements? Or do they use their right hand like right-handed people? **Is there any research into this matter with published numbers?**

Comment: See http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/346/left-handed-persons-and-usability - the [second answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/491/2287) sounds quite likely. tl;dr: They use the right hand, too.

Comment: Hmm, i'm a righty and I hold it with my left hand. I use my left thumb tp do stuff, but my right index finger pitches in when I type. But that's probably just me :\

Comment: I'm right-handed and I use ***all*** phones with my left hand. AFAIK, most people do the same: use the phone with the non-dominant hand.

Comment: I'm left handed and I always use my left hand and my left hand thumb to navigate and write. Both in landscape mode and portrait mode. If I need to pinch (for example to zoom) I use my right hand while holding it with my left.

Comment: I think that many people use which ever hand is available, no matter which hand is their dominate one. Unfortunately, to type without stretching your thumb and with minimal typos you need to hold the phone with one hand and use the interface with your other. In practice this is probably not always done.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the input! Now, how do I close select the best answer if all of you used comments instead?

Comment: I am left handed. If I am at the meeting and need to write I will use my phone in my right hand navigating with a thumb and write with left. Overall I think navigation with thumb is easy for me with both hands. Although If I need to hit a small target I am more likely to use my left pointing finger.

Comment: Choose the best comment and ask the writer (using a comment) to write it out as an answer :-)

Comment: "I do it this way" unfortunately is not an answer, which is why I've tried to focus the question around data so it can make a useful resource

Comment: I'm right handed and always hold the phone or tablet with my right hand and use my left hand finger to operate it

Comment: I'd just like to mention the annoying fact that, since Latin text reads left to right, operating a phone with one's left hand means that the thumb tends to obscure the text. Additionally, justifying text on the right, such as with Android's "Force RtL" means that text blurbs will be jagged on the left and less easily scanned. So you're out of luck if for some reason you can't operate a phone with your right hand. Unless you care to learn Arabic, that is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got inspired, did some digging in my search engine of choice and found a very [recent study by Henry Ford Hospital](http://www.henryford.com/body.cfm?id=46335&action=detail&ref=1540) (published in February 2012) that gives a more or less clear answer on the debate:

### People hold phones in the hand that is opposite to the dominant side of the *brain* (where speech & hearing centers are located).

This means that the majority (70%) of right-handed people do indeed hold it with their right hand and left-handed people with their left hand because their speech centers are in the left and right hemispheres respectively.

However, there're still 30% of people who use the non-dominant hand for phones (like me) and people who are supposedly ambidextrous.

Comment: Nice study, but it's really about which *ear* people use to speak on the phone, rather than which hand they use to operate the phone. Speaking into it doesn't use the same physical interactions as touching, pinching and dragging elements on the screen do.

Comment: @JonW: That depends on overall dexterity of the hand, in which they're holding the device (i.e older people with bad finger joints use 2 hands to operate a mobile phone).

Comment: So, does this mean that hand dominance doesn't play any role in which hand people use to hold their smartphone?

Comment: @YosefWaysman Yes, at least for tasks related to calling it depends on the location of speech & hearing centers of the brain. For non-calling tasks, it may depend on the dominant hand but I haven't seen such research yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am left handed, and I do use my thumb to tap UI elements wile holding a smartphone in my right hand.

It seems as though left handed people tend to hold a smartphone with their right hand, as holding a smartphone does not require a lot of dexterity. Also, smartphones are usually optimized for right handed people, as the majority of humans are, in fact, right handed.

However, it all comes down to a person's preference. For example, it's like with computer mice - most left handed people will use their right hand to control the mouse, because almost all mice are ergonomically designed to fit someones right hand. Now, computer mice are being created for left handed people to use, but are not very popular because most of us lefties have grown up moving the mouse with our right hand and typing with our left hand. If I had to type with my right hand and move the mouse with my left hand, I wouldn't be nearly as efficient. It would be like learning to use a computer all over again.

Comment: Sorry for the wall of text. I'm usually on Arqade, so I'm not really sure how to format answers on here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Hunger. You're personal case does help me understand better, but I was hoping for more research-based data.

Comment: Then I suggest the link ThiefMaster commented.