# Setting for left-handed users

Tags: usability, accessibility, tablet

This application has a ribbon. If you pull a panel opens. For left-handed users it's a little uncomfortable, while opening the panel, arm occludes part of the screen and interferes with their intent to a quick glance.

One problem is that the application has no settings panel. And do not will have.
The other one is that the app should not decide where put the ribbon based on device settings. The user should decide. (The app could suggest.)

I'm looking for ideas, suggestions to make it configurable (without a setting panel).

Ribbon Example:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIucme.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

EDIT:

I think in something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa18se.png)</sup>

Comment: Related: [For touchscreen interaction, are there benefits to knowing a user's preferred hand?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39244/for-touchscreen-interaction-are-there-benefits-to-knowing-a-users-preferred-ha)

Answer (score 2):

As a left-hander myself I don't really see the need for something like this. If I use any smartphone in landscape mode, I automatically (and so do most of my peers) use both hands and therefore able to touch whatever I want to more or less comfortably.

So IMH-left-hander-O: don't worry about us left-handers, unless the app will usually be handled one-handed only

Answer (score 1):

I use both hands with my phone and I cannot touch anything without occluding the think I want to touch regardless of which hand I use... So perhaps there is no problem at all?

Also when I use the thumb of the hand holding the phone (anyone else ever held a shopping bag in their other hand?), sliding from the left side is more comfortable to do with my left hand.

1 way to make it configurable would be to slide it always from the "bottom" of the phone and you can turn your phone either way to make it slide from left/right...

Given you have an info from actual left-handed users (I kindly assume the statement "For left-handed users it's a little uncomfortable" comes from an actual user and not from your prejudice), did you ask them what would they prefer?

If having a settings menu is not a real possibility (not sure what could ever be a good reason for not having any settings, but I am sure you do have a good reason) and you really really need to treat left-handed users differently, there is always a possibility to offer 2 apps (1 for righties, 1 for lefties)...